# on click scroll to element

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

Hi there I have a problem. I need scroll to element from anchor on click but I get error:

> SyntaxError: missing } after property list

scrollTop: `$( $(this).attr('href') )element.offset().top`

```
/* jQuery scroll to element on click */

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('nav#site-navigation ul li').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
    });

});
```

anchor is in WP navigation menu

Comment: Your code should **work just fine**. You have in some lines before something unclosed. Console is your friend. See the line-number that's trowing the error. (Or use a better IDE - code/editor, will show those errors right away.)

Comment: scrollT...ment.js (line 7, col 44)

Comment: `scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') )element.offset().top` what's this? Is that some code you actually use or is a question comment?

Comment: that is my last copy/pase log error. 'element.offset 'is my previusly trying to get a funcionalty of script. forget that i will change

Comment: Added an example below. Should work just fine now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `<li>` element does not have a `href` attribute!
Use it's child `<a>` element instead

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('nav#site-navigation ul li a').click(function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
      }, 1000);
    });

});
```

```css
nav{position:fixed;top:20px;}
.page{height:100vh;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="site-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="home" class="page">HOME</div>
<div id="about" class="page">ABOUT</div>
<div id="contact" class="page">CONTACT</div>
```

Also, don't forget to use `.stop()` to clear the animation queue

Comment: If that worked for you please accept his answer so that this question gets closed and Roko gets his reward.